# XPath Evaluation in Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am having an issue getting the data from an xpath using Html Agility Pack in a C#/.NET web scraper.

The web page: https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=022796901200.

I am scraping the item price:
Chrome says the xpath is: //*[@id="mainContainer"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span
While the full xpath is: /html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span

The string result of (var productPrice = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span");) is returning empty, however the web page indicates it should be 6.99.

Is there an issue with Html Agility Pack that I am missing?

Comment: Reason its not going to evaluate correctly is because chrome is rendering the page with javascripts and all where HtmlAgilityPack only looks at the raw HTML page. I dont believe there is any way of rendering the page with javascripts easily that I know of.

Comment: Shouldn't you at least be able to evaluate the ID or Class? That should include the Java scripting right?